# Unknown policy-vendor error in snap package review

Tags: application-development, packaging, snap

I am trying to package an application in snap format, but When I do

```
snap-review olam_0.1_amd64.snap
```

It shows this error

```
 - security-snap-v2:policy-vendor
    unknown policy-vendor 'ubuntu-core'
```

How do I fix it? I don't have any lines containing policy vendor in snap config.

I am using `click-reviewers-tools` version 0.43~14.04.1

Comment: I'll ask around why the new version hasn't hit xenial yet.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Snaps built using `snapcraft` should pass reviews using the latest click-reviewers-tools. If in doubt, check out the source using

```
bzr branch lp:click-reviewers-tools
cd click-reviewers-tools
./bin/snap-review <your.snap>
```